# What row is violating this check constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm trying to add the following check constraint to the `raffle_participant` table:

```
ALTER TABLE raffle_participant ADD CONSTRAINT ck_raffle_participant_total_purchased_le_ticket_limit CHECK (tickets_purchased_in_raffle(raffle_id) <= get_ticket_limit(raffle_id))
```

When I execute the above command, I get back:

```
ERROR:  check constraint "ck_raffle_participant_total_purchased_le_ticket_limit" of relation "raffle_participant" is violated by some row
```

It would appear to me that all the rows within the `raffle_participant` table satisfy the constraint. What am I not understanding here? Why is the check constraint being violated on the existing data?

Using PostgreSQL version 13.6.

Edit:
I've tried the following queries to figure out what rows are violating the constraint and it would appear none of them do.

```
development=# select (select sum(p.tickets_purchased) from raffle_participant p where p.raffle_id = 2) <= (select r.ticket_limit from raffle r where r.id = 2);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

development=# select (select sum(p.tickets_purchased) from raffle_participant p where p.raffle_id = 3) <= (select r.ticket_limit from raffle r where r.id = 3);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

development=# select (select sum(p.tickets_purchased) from raffle_participant p where p.raffle_id = 4) <= (select r.ticket_limit from raffle r where r.id = 4);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

### raffle table

#### Schema

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | integer |  | not null | generated always as identity |
| item_name | character varying(40) |  | not null |  |
| item_value | bigint |  | not null |  |
| ticket_limit | integer |  | not null |  |
| ticket_price | bigint |  | not null |  |
| user_ticket_limit | integer |  | not null |  |
| ended_on | timestamp with time zone |  |  |  |
| winner_id | bigint |  |  |  |

#### Data

| id | item_name | item_value | ticket_limit | ticket_price | user_ticket_limit | ended_on | winner_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item | 10 | 10 | 10 | 2 | 2022-04-27 17:46:01.271025+00 |  |
| 2 | item | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 2022-04-27 17:55:28.783744+00 | 151150118697959424 |
| 3 | item | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 2022-04-27 20:32:13.588843+00 | 151150118697959424 |
| 4 | item | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |  |  |

### raffle_participant table

#### Schema

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raffle_id | integer |  | not null |  |
| user_id | bigint |  | not null |  |
| tickets_purchased | integer |  | not null |  |

#### Data

| raffle_id | user_id | tickets_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 151150118697959424 | 10 |
| 3 | 151150118697959424 | 10 |
| 4 | 151150118697959424 | 3 |

### tickets_purchased_in_raffle function

```
CREATE FUNCTION tickets_purchased_in_raffle (IN raffle_id raffle.id%TYPE) 
  RETURNS raffle_participant.tickets_purchased%TYPE AS
  $$ 
    SELECT SUM(p.tickets_purchased) FROM raffle_participant p WHERE p.raffle_id = raffle_id 
  $$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

### get_ticket_limit function

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_ticket_limit (IN raffle_id raffle.id%TYPE) 
  RETURNS raffle.ticket_limit%TYPE AS
  $$
    SELECT r.ticket_limit FROM raffle r WHERE r.id = raffle_id 
  $$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Comment: this is what failed: `(tickets_purchased_in_raffle(raffle_id) <= get_ticket_limit(raffle_id))`

Comment: What do you mean? Is the syntax of that check constraint invalid? My problem is that I am unable to add the constraint to the table with the shown data. Looking at the data, there appears to be no violating rows.

Comment: no when postgres tries to add the constraint, it tests all rows, and you have some that violates that, so there is at least one row that has (tickets_purchased_in_raffle(raffle_id) > get_ticket_limit(raffle_id)), so make a SELECT and chelc that first

Comment: FYI, what you are doing is not a good idea. From here [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): "Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row ...". Cheating by using a function is not the way to get around this. There is no dependency tracking on `CHECK`, so it very possible that on migrating this to a new database will fail because the `CHECK` is run before the functions it needs are loaded. For this sort of thing use a trigger.

Comment: I noticed you did not run a check for `raffle_id = 1`. It is best to take the error as true and look for the exception to the rule that is causing the `CHECK` to fail.  Also remember `sum()` where a `raffle_id` does not exist is `NULL` and `NULL <= <some_number>` is going to be `NULL` not 't' or 'f'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my input argument, `raffle_id`, to `tickets_purchased_in_raffle` was being shadowed by the column name, `raffle_id`, of `raffle_participant`. By changing the argument name to `rid`, I was able to successfully add the check constraint.

Comment: I repeat my warning, do not do this. Using a function and/or referring to rows in another table is going to cause you problems. For a more in depth explanation see [Check Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS), in particular the **Note** part.

Comment: Noted. I will look into using triggers for this. Thanks